# C# remove duplicate dictionary items from List<>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I a collection of dictionary items in a list:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> inputData = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(inputs);    
List<Dictionary<string, string>> itemStack = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Now what I want to do is for each inputData dictionary item I want to check if itemStack has the same value (Dictionary Item) already.

I was thinking it would be like?

```
foreach (var item in inputData)
{
  if(!itemStack.Contains(item){ itemStack.Add(item)}
  else{ //Duplicate found}
}
```

It doesn't really check the items values inside? It just assumes that it doesn't have it...
All i want is if itemStack contains and item that is already in the stack don't include it.
I know I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks,

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> is not enough? Why making List of Dictionary<string, string> ?

Comment: In which way is this related to ASP.NET?

Comment: @Tomas I'm iterating through each item to check if its duplicate

@Tim just because its in the event of an asp.net controller on this site. I'm scrubbing post results and trying to remove duplicate entries.

Comment: @Do you really need *multiple dictionaries*? That's hardly believable, unless you have a language for each dictionary, or something like that. Can you convince us?

Comment: I guess I dont'. At first, I was just using one dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this isn't quite a full answer but it's what I did.

So I have a List of items and instead of doing a full compare to whats in an List(Hence the other considered) I just did a single item check:

```
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["itemId"]))
 {
    alert.DaleksApproaching(item["itemId"]);
 }
```

So when it does see it has a value it just does another event to get rid of it.
The idea of using  LINQ and the method approaches about(Contains and Distinct)I like. I have yet to try that, but I plan on doing that. For this it doesn't use LINQ :(

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is reference type, so it doesn't check the "deep" value like you expected.

You will have to write your own "Contains" method, either as totally separate method or extension of the Dictionary itself then use it instead, for example:

```
 if(!MyContains(itemStack, item)){ itemStack.Add(item)}
```

Comment: +1: The default "Equals" check for two dictionaries will just check whether the two objects are exactly the same (i.e. take up the same place in memory).

Answer (score 0):

True that a HashSet would be better, but if you want to do it here, try this (assuming you are filtering duplicate keys only):

```
foreach (var item in inputData.Keys)
{
    if (itemStack.Where(x => x.Key == item.Key).Count() > 0)
              // There was a duplicate
}
```

Or, if you only care when the data is coming out you can call:

```
itemStack.Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your way is right. On my mind, HashSet is good, but when you add a new element, it performs the same test on the contents of the same items.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your initial problem statement, you might do something like this:

```
var aggregateKnownKeys = itemStack.SelectMany(d => d.Keys);
itemStack.AddRange(
    inputData.Select(d=> d.Where(p => !aggregateKnownKeys.Contains(p.Key))
                          .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value)));
```

If you only need to combine two dictionaries then you could do this to skip keys that exist in itemStack:

```
var inputData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var itemStack = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var oldStack = itemStack;
itemStack = new[] { inputData.SkipWhile(d => oldStack.Keys.Contains(d.Key)), itemStack }
   .SelectMany(d => d)
   .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```